My boss is going to retire
My boss shared with me about a month ago that he will be retired by the end of this year. He also mentioned in his 1 on 1 formal announcement that his replacement for this kind of position (VP) usually will bring with him his own crews.
Within these months, he has been trying to wrap up, plan for each of the team member and the team what it will be like for years ahead. Including asking me to transitioning all my jobs duties to another fairly new hires.
This one year old new hire often comes to his office and asks questions, have talks and laugh and he shared lots of business insights with this person. This person was supposed to be hired to pick up my responsibilities so I can free for other responsibilities. My boss kept asking me to pass and formal train this new hire but this new hire wasn’t stand up to my standard; however, my boss thinks this new hire is capable and in fact, he gives this new hire more responsibilities than to me. Things that I would think should be mine responsibilities but he gave it to this new hire.
I wasn’t cool about it and he noticed my black face. He called me to his office and asked “I noticed something different” and I blasted out my unstable emotions. And said loudly “I’m looking for jobs and asked him to wish me luck” (but I have no intention to leave) I even told him it’s “none of my business” when he said “did I share with you that such is going to launch this”? The “this” is a project that the new hire managed.
Days later, I asked him for a 1on1 and I asked him I want to know what are my responsibilities now since most of my tasks got passed out. He told me if I wanted, I can take the “this” project. He goes on asking me what I wanted to do? And also goes on the teach me what I should say in my job interview. After the talks, he went and sent me lots of emails saying this and this is going on. Also, I noticed he sent me an email about a project that going on, but very broad; instead, I saw the new hire was sitting in that meeting for that project already.
What should I do? What is his perspective?
Should I have another meeting with him? We are going to have annual review within this month. Should I wait and should I be honest of what I think and how I feel?

We cannot tell you what to do. What do you want to achieve?

I just want a stable job.
He has been saying nice things of me in meeting with big big boss and our team. So I am confused of what his plans are.

I’m confused about your goals here. As you describe it, you rejected just about every task related to your transition going forward, said you were about to quit, and rejected all projects offered to you. Yet it reads as if you expected to handle these tasks, not quit, and handle the projects. Is this just about bitterness towards the new hire?

Cuz I don’t quite understand. On one hand, he said that I’m a contributor, I have done excellent job but on the other hand, not adding anything to my plate.
I won’t want to take the “this” project cuz I don’t want to steal the project from other. That’s not the right thing to do. But I’m trying to understand h to the mentality of my boss here.
He shared about what’s going on after I asked for more responsibilities but all he shared is the title.

"Transitioning all my job duties to another fairly new hire." - This sounds like you are training your replacement. That isn't cool, or are you being assigned these new hires under your supervision, and you are transitioning to a new role?

You lost control - not great, but understandable.
Your boss offered you options that they didn't. Basically a second chance since you showed that you don't handle transistion well.
Simple truth - The higher up the manager, the more likely they will bring their own people with them. It isn't cronyism in most cases, it helps them with success.
You hast a case to be a team member. Hopefully, that failure didn't occur in front of the new team.
Your retiring manager IS TRYING to take care of you. YOU MUST MEET THEM HALF WAY.
There isn't a guarentee that it will work out. But if you don't try, it can't work out.
What should you do? Look forward. The past is gone. If you can't, quickly get a new job.
Random internet people can't make your choices for you.
